# Dataset for clothing

Tags: data-request

I'm looking for a dataset for at least one product segment with at least 1000 records and with attributes like:

- product name,
- product price,
- shipping type (free or customer paid)
- monthly sales ($)
- geographic region
- no. of customers who bought the product,
- customer type (new or existing)